# How do we correctly handle a power source and a capacitor in parallel?

Tags: electricity, voltage, capacitance

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$[image]

Here $V$ is an alternating supply, $R$ is a fixed resistor and $C$ is an capacitor. All components, including the diode, are ideal. Say $V(t)=V_\max\sin\omega t$ - with orientation such that the current initially passes through the diode - and that the capacitor is initially uncharged.

To model this situation I was able to notice, by applying the current laws, that when $\sin\omega t<0$ no current can go through the supply - because no current can go through the diode. Then the circuit is just a simple capacitor discharge circuit and the following ODE is satisfied, where $Q$ is the charge on the capacitor: $$-R\frac{\d Q}{\d t}=\frac{Q}{C}$$

[image]

But when $\sin\omega t>0$ I'm pretty stuck. By the voltage laws I know it should be true that $RI_2$ equals the voltage across the capacitor i.e. $Q/C$, and $I_1=\frac{\d Q}{\d t}$ is what I ultimately want to find so that I can setup an ODE to solve. Of course $I=I_1+I_2$.

What's troubling me is the conceptual question of whether or not capacitors have resistance. I'm torn between saying, $V_\max\sin\omega t=RI$ "because the overall resistance of the circuit is $R$" and between thinking that that argument is nonsense. If I run with this assumption for now, I arrive at: $$V_\max\sin\omega t-\frac{Q}{C}=R\frac{\d Q}{\d t}$$Which is solvable.

However, I'm inclined to say that that's wrong, because the solutions to the ODEs (appropriately glued together with initial conditions at $t=\pi/\omega$ and $t=0$) on $[0,2\pi/\omega]$ give me an allegedly incorrect value in a question I was answering. I've graphically checked that my equations solve the ODEs correctly, so the error isn't there. The error has to be in the modelling assumptions I've made.

Conceptually, I really don't know how to confirm or deny the assumption $V_\max\sin\omega t=RI$. The cumulative effect of the capacitor source and the alternating source *in parallel* is seriously confusing me - I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your circuit has two regimes of operation: one where the diode is conducting, and one where it is not. When the diode is *not* conducting, we have

$$C \ \frac{d V_B}{d T} = I_1, \\
V_B = I_2 R, \\
I_2 = -I_1,
$$

which we can solve for $d V_B / d T$ to obtain

$$\frac{d V_B}{d T} = - \frac{V_B}{R C}.$$

Once we've figured out the initial conditions for this differential equation, we'll be able to solve it, and then we can plug the solution into the above in order to find $I_1$ and $I_2$.

When the diode *is* conducting, the voltage source, capacitor, and resistor are all (effectively) in parallel. Components in parallel have the same voltage, and the voltage source determines its own voltage, so the voltages across the capacitor and resistor must match the voltage source. So we have

$$V_B = V_A, \\
I_1 = C \ \frac{d V_B}{d T} = C \ \frac{d V_A}{d T}, \\
I_2 = \frac{V_B}{R} = \frac{V_A}{R},
$$

and we can find $I_1$ and $I_2$ simply by plugging in $V_A = V_{\text{max}} \sin (\omega t)$.

The tricky part is knowing when the circuit switches between regimes. Initially, the diode conducts, but it will stop conducting at a time where both regimes make the same prediction. In other words, it will stop conducting at a time when

$$\frac{d V_A}{d T} = - \frac{V_A}{R C}.$$

We can solve this equation to find the initial conditions for the differential equation where the diode is not conducting. That will give us an exact solution for $V_B$ during that time period, and the diode will begin conducting again when $V_A$ and $V_B$ become equal again. The bad news is that the equation for this will have a sine on one side and an exponential on the other side, so the solution probably won't have a closed form. The good news is that the time that the diode begins conducting again doesn't matter for the long-term behavior of the circuit.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try this. The point about everything being effectively in parallel and therefore all voltages are the same, this helped.

Comment: I've made it make sense. Thanks again - I'm now able to get the right answer on the problem

Comment: Although - how do I know $I_1=CdV_B/dt$ and not $I_1=-CdV_B/dt$? After all, I could have drawn $I_1$ pointing in a different direction, and it seems a bit arbitrary (the sign corresponding to charging / discharging, it depends on which end of the capacitor is the positive plate and which is the negative plate, which a priori I don't know?)

Comment: @FShrike Well, suppose you have a capacitor, and assume that at one of the capacitor's terminals has a constant potential. Then if the potential at the second terminal rises, current will flow into the second terminal; if the potential at the second terminal falls, current will flow out of the second terminal. In our case here, as $V_B$ rises, current must flow into the $V_B$ side of the capacitor, and you've defined $I_1$ as being positive when that happens. If you had drawn the $I_1$ arrow pointing towards $V_B$ instead of away from it, the formula would indeed then be $I_1 = - C dV_b/dt$.

Comment: "If the potential at the second terminal rises, current will flow into the second terminal" - why is that? Currents want to flow from points of more positive potential to points of more negative potential, so if the potential at the second terminal rises then current is less inclined to flow that way.

Comment: @FShrike Yes, that's correct. Specifically, suppose we have a capacitor whose two terminals are called $X$ and $Y$, and initially, both terminals have the same potential. Then suppose that we keep the potential at $X$ constant, but we start raising the potential at $Y$ higher and higher. As the potential increases, the current begins to "want" to flow from $Y$ to $X$, and that "desire" goes stronger and stronger. And so that's exactly what happens: current flows from $Y$ to $X$, through the capacitor.

Comment: (To be precise, current flows from $Y$ onto one plate of the capacitor, and from the other plate of the capacitor into $X$. However, this is a mere implementation detail, so to speak. For most practical purposes, we can imagine that the current really is going _through_ the capacitor.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I found another way to justify it, does it look ok to you? (as you can tell, physics is not my strong suit) The energy stored on the capacitor is $E=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$ if $V$ is the potential difference across it. Let's label the two terminals $X$ and $Y$, and let's define $V:=Y-X$. If we label the current $Y\to X$ as $I$, then with this orientation the power equation $VI=\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}=CV\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is correct. Dividing through by $V$ finds $I=C\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$ as desired (this orientation matches yours).

Comment: ^ "$Y-X$" should read: "$V_Y-V_X$" where $V_\bullet$ is the potential at a point

Comment: @FShrike Yep, it looks to me like you've correctly used the energy formula to derive the magnitude and direction of the current.

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answers are pretty good. I will make one general remark in addition. Not only does a real capacitor have resistance, it also has an inductance. The same is true for a diode and the voltage source. Ideal circuit elements are approximations of real electric components. In some cases these approximations are good ones, like for RC and RL-circuits in which all the voltages and currents are well defined all the time. But if we try to make a parallel circuit with two ideal voltage sources, then we will find that the system of equations doesn't have a solution if the two voltages are unequal. It would take an infinite current to satisfy the equations. However, of we are allowing for voltage sources to have a finite internal resistance, then we end up with a finite current. Similarly, if we allow for a stray inductance term, then the solution becomes a current that is increasing linear in time. This fixes the problem with unsolvable equations.

Considering stray resistance, inductance and capacitance is also quite "natural" because real voltage sources have typical (linearized) series resistance in the range of mOhm (car batteries) to several Ohm (for a small lithium cell or an unregulated power supply with a small transformer). Capacitors exhibit series resistances in the ten to hundred mOhm range. All of these components have series inductances of ten to hundreds of nH unless we are very careful with the wiring. These are just typical engineering estimates that an experienced circuit designer will use unless he has done actual measurements on these components.

Why is this important? It matters because these stray impedances determine in which frequency range the calculations/circuit simulations using ideal circuit elements are good approximations. For example, a 1uF capacitor with 100nH wiring impedance will become a resonant LC circuit with a resonance frequency of roughly 500kHz. The effective impedance of the ideal capacitor at that frequency is on the order of 0.3Ohm. Since the series resistance is typically smaller by an order of magnitude, the capacitor will actually behave like a resonance circuit with a Q in the range of ten. That's a very significant deviation from the ideal circuit which will "get us" in many applications. Even audio circuit designs that are trying to filter power supplies with large numbers of high quality capacitors are therefor more a show of the ignorance of the designer of basic physics than good design practice (there are other ways to deal with those problems than capacitor graveyards). It gets increasingly worse at higher frequencies. This example is just to show that there is no "magic" frequency below which we can ignore non-ideal circuit behavior. It always depends on the application and in my experience one should never "believe that the ideal circuit is good enough". One should always ask the question what non-ideal behavior does to it and do some back of the envelope calculations to make sure that it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\frac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dt}R=\frac QC$$

No, you are missing a very important minus sign here.

> when $\sin\omega t<0$ no current can go through the supply - because no current can go through the diode.

This is also the wrong criterion. It is actually when $V_\text{max}\sin\omega t\leqslant\dfrac QC$ that will have no current flowing through the diode.

> What's troubling me is the conceptual question of whether or not capacitors have resistance.

Real world capacitors have leakage current, i.e. finite resistances. The ideal case you are dealing with has infinite resistance and no leakage current.

> $$V_\text{max}\sin\omega t=IR$$

Is false.

---

The thing you should be doing, is solving the discharging of the capacitor as a function of time. Then you can find the rate of the discharging nearby the peak value of $V_\text{max}$. Then you can do case by case analysis, checking when the rate of discharging is slower or faster than the decrease in voltage. You simply need the value of $T$ such that $V_\text{max}\sin\omega T=\dfrac QC$ and the slopes take over from one regime to the other.

You need all that to create the correct patchwork solution for this idealised problem.

Comment: $V_\max\sin\omega t=IR$ is false - so, as I was trying to focus on, what *is* the correct way to link $I$ with the voltage $V_\max\sin\omega t$? Thanks for the point about $V_\max\sin\omega t\le\frac{Q}{C}$ being the correct criterion, I'll try to see if that adjustment gives me correct numbers